# How to ignore route with New Relic for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, newrelic

I have a nodejs app which has the new relic module installed.
Everything is set up but I don't know how to exclude a route from the new relic tracker.
I have this script at `http://www.website.com/match/findMatch` which usually takes at least 4 seconds and I want to add it to the exclusion list.
The rest of the scripts usually take 0.1s but this one makes my ApDex give out alerts which aren't correct.
I already have this in my conf file because I use websockets:

```
rules : {
  ignore : [
    '^\/socket\.io\/.*\/xhr-polling',
    '^\/socket\.io\/.*\/websocket',
  ]
}
```

I've read the docs [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/supported-features/nodejs-agent-api) 3 times but still don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add a new `ignore` rule that matches requests to `http://www.website.com/match/findMatch`.

Rules can be strings or regular expressions (like the socket.io examples). If the request you want to ignore is *always* `http://www.website.com/match/findMatch` (not, for example, `http://www.website.com/match/findMatch?q=foo`, you can do this:

```
rules : {
  ignore : [
    '^\/socket\.io\/.*\/xhr-polling',
    '^\/socket\.io\/.*\/websocket',
    'http://www.website.com/match/findMatch'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. What if parameters are sent via POST, do I have to add anything else here?

Comment: I don't believe anything special is required for POST. Noticed NR support also added answered a [similar question in the forums](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/how-to-ignore-route-with-new-relic-for-nodejs/30641) -- you might want to consider ignoring the route in code (vs blacklist) using `newrelic.setIgnoreTransaction(ignored)`.